# Binding MySQL strings that have a column ID to that ID in PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have an array composed by IDs in default keys, I want to link these IDs with there correspondent description in a MySQL table composed by these IDs and the description in different columns. Example of the Table and Array below:

```
Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 12
[2] => 17
[3] => 21
[4] => 26
)

+----+----------------------------+
| ID | description                |
+----+----------------------------+
| 1  | Example Description        |
+----+----------------------------+
| 2  | Wow, this is a description |
+----+----------------------------+
| 3  | Amazing description        |
+----+----------------------------+
| 4  | Description for ID4        |
+----+----------------------------+
| 5  | Yes, another description   |
+----+----------------------------+
```

The output have to look like the following(with or without commas) :

```
Description, Another description, description...
```

The array is named '$arraymanutenzionehwos' and the table 'interventi_hwos'

I have provided general case, but if needed I can provide my code and all the needed details.

The main process of the script were to pick the ID in each element of the array and bind it to the proper description in the Mysql table column.

**Thanks a lot**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use a query something like this:

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT description ORDER BY description SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS d
   FROM interventi_hwos
  WHERE id IN (1,12,17,21,26)
```

This will yield one row containing one column with the comma-concatenated string you want.

To do that from php you're going to need to do something like this to put together your query string.

```
$query = <<< 'ENDQUERY'
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT description ORDER BY description SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS d
  FROM interventi_hwos
 WHERE id IN 
ENDQUERY
$query .= ' (' . implode( ',', array_filter($arraymanutenzionehwos, 'is_int') . ')';
```

Notice that this sanitizes your array by eliminating any item from it that isn't an integer. That's helpful to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Tested and gave the best execution times! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Without more details it's hard to provide a complete solution, but here is a query you can use:

```
$sql = "
SELECT description FROM interventi_hwos
WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', $arraymanutenzionehwos). ")
ORDER BY FIELD(id, " . implode(',', $arraymanutenzionehwos). ")
";
```

Given your example data, this will produce a query like:

```
SELECT description FROM interventi_hwos
WHERE id IN (1,12,17,21,26)
ORDER BY FIELD (id, 1,12,17,21,26)
```

[**See a demo of this query**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2628c/1)

This will give you the list of descriptions based on the id's in your array, in the same order as the original id array. You can use PHP to format the resulting array however you please. Note, if the order of the result doesn't matter, remove the ORDER BY clause.